# Using SDF 1.5 with Gazebo 2.22

Tags: gazebo-2.2, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Currently, I'm trying to use the world files found in here: [https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/commits/703385171b613f1cdaea925a61f2d93040478955#chg-worlds/sphere_atlas_demo.world"](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/commits/703385171b613f1cdaea925a61f2d93040478955#chg-worlds/sphere_atlas_demo.world%22). However, I noticed they are all in SDF 1.5. Can SDF 1.5 be used with Gazebo 2.22?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/6794/using-sdf-1.5-with-gazebo-2.22/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/835/k.-zeng/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 103 on 2014-08-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe you will need to build gazebo 2.2 from source to use sdf 1.5

---

Originally posted by [scpeters](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/109/scpeters/) with karma: 2861 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0